# There is a column named ... it cannot be referenced from this part of the query sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

```
 WITH upt as (
 UPDATE backend."orders" SET "statusId" = 5
 WHERE "userId" IN (177962,88265) and "statusId" IN (0,1,2,3,4) RETURNING *
)
 INSERT INTO __test_result(orderid) VALUES ((SELECT orderid FROM upt))
```

Need to update and log data,getting this error

```
ERROR: column "orderid" does not exist Hint: There is a column named 
"orderid" in table "__test_result", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

How can I insert in table for all "upt" rows?It must look

```
"upt.orderid","jsonb for that orderid"
```

for every order jsonb must be created from "upt" column with same orderid

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a `select` as the source for an insert (for multiple rows) do not use the `values` clause, use the select directly: `insert into .. select ...`.

So in your case:

```
WITH upt as (
  UPDATE backend."orders" 
     SET "statusId" = 5
  WHERE "userId" IN (177962,88265) 
    and "statusId" IN (0,1,2,3,4) 
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO __test_result(orderid) 
SELECT orderid 
FROM upt;
```

Comment: OK,and what about this ?
    INSERT INTO __test_result(orderid,prop) 
    SELECT "orderId",jsonb_build_object('4',4) as prop 
    FROM upt

Comment: Same thing, just with two columns